# How can I normalize the columns when calling up a .describe function in python? I want an output of 2 decimal places

Tags: python, decimal, describe

[image]

How can I normalize the columns when calling up a .describe function in python? I want an output of two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

To round to two decimal place, you have a few options choose which one depending on your needs.

The simplest option is the build-it `round` fuction. I takes the number you want to round and the precision (default for precision is to round to nearest whole number). This, however rounds toward even numbers, so it is not always optimal.

```
round(1.004, 2) --> 1.0
round(1.005, 2) --> 1.01 # Rounds up on 5
round(1.006, 2) --> 1.01
round(2.004, 2) --> 2.0
round(2.005, 2) --> 2.0  # Rounds down on 5
round(2.006, 2) --> 2.01
```

---

The second option is to use the `decimal` library (part of standard library).

`Decimal(NUMBER).quantize(Decimal(10**PRECISION), rounding=MODE)`

Replace `NUMBER`, `PRECISION` and `MODE` with your number, precision and chosen mode. There are a number of modes, and these are the descriptions from the docs.

- `ROUND_CEILING` - Round towards Infinity.
- `ROUND_DOWN` - Round towards zero.
- `ROUND_FLOOR` - Round towards -Infinity.
- `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` - Round to nearest with ties going towards zero.
- `ROUND_HALF_EVEN` - Round to nearest with ties going to nearest even
  integer.
- `ROUND_HALF_UP` - Round to nearest with ties going away from zero.
- `ROUND_UP` - Round away from zero.
- `ROUND_05UP` - Round away from zero if last digit after rounding towards zero would have been 0 or 5; otherwise round towards zero.

`ROUND_HALF_EVEN` has the same functionality as the `round` function.

`ROUND_05UP` is equivalent to `ROUND_UP` when rounding to a power of ten (like in the question.)

---

If `round` feels weird and the second option feels like overkill, you could do `int(NUMBER * (10 ** 2)) // (10 ** 2)`.

Hope this helps you with whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I know its a bit much, but the behavior of `round` just feels so weird to me!

Comment: .describe is autodataframe of values shown in thr poc above how can I apply round into the .describe func?